# Text on hover not centering properly CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying create a hover effect which displays the text centered in the image, both vertically and horizontally. My main problem is that the text keeps staying on top of the image and when I try to navigate it using percentages or pixels, the entire hover effect background changes its proportion.

In this JS fiddle you can see what I'm doing, just hover over the left image in order to achieve the effect. The text just appears on the top, while it shouldn't.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18288/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row " id= "faded">   
                            <img src = "img/logo.png" class ="img-responsive" id = "logo">


                    <div class = "col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >

                    <img src = "img/1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" id ="left-image">
                            <div class = "carousel-caption" id = "pricing">
                                <h2>PRICING</h2>
                            </div>


                            <div class = "text">

                                HAIRCUT  $45<br>
                                SHAVE     $45<br>
                                COMBO     $80<br>

                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                    <img src = "img/2.jpg" class = "img-responsive" id = "middle-image">
                    <div class ="carousel-caption" id = "about-us">
                        <h2> ABOUT US </h2>
                    </div>

                    <img src = "img/3.jpg" class = "img-responsive" id= "mid-image">
                        <div class ="carousel-caption" id = "contact-us">
                        <h2> CONTACT US </h2>
                    </div>

                    </div>



                    <div class = " col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <img src = "img/4.jpg" class = "img-responsive" id = "right-image">
                        <div class ="carousel-caption" id = "appointments">
                        <h3> APPOINTMENTS </h3>
                         </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code used:

```
#logo{
height: 10%;
width:15%;
}
.col-md-6, .col-md-3{
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
}
.img-responsive{
margin-left:0px;
padding-left:0px;
}

#pricing{
bottom:89%;
left:-30%;
}

#about-us{
bottom:89%;
left: -55%;
}

#contact-us{
bottom: 39%;
right:-53%;
}

#appointments{
bottom:89%;
left:-15%;
}

.text {  
    background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.83);
    position: absolute;  
    color: black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2.5em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;   
    pointer-events:none;
}  

 #left-image:hover ~ .text {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your css you need to add

```
padding-top: 50%;
```

like so -

```
.text {  
    background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.83);
    position: absolute;  
    color: black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top 50%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2.5em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;   
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

`padding` changes the distance from the border, from the inside out. see - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!